# Drupal commerce show taxonomy image in product variation

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

I'm trying to change the view of the product variation.
Let's say I'm selling t-shirt in different color so I create the taxonomy with the color and a small image of the color.
I create the term reference in product and enable the "Attribute field settings".
Now when i display a product i should be able so see the image of the taxonomy to choose the color but it shows me just the title in a select list or radio button. How can I override it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [Commerce Fancy Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes) module.

Comment: Hi Bojan, I've just read about it here http://drupal.org/node/1180016 but here you need to add the hex color... I was trying to get the image from the taxonomy and I'm sure there should be a method.

Comment: The mechanism is the same (you still need the same module). 
Hex color + formatter, or image, works the same.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Maybe the hexadecimal looks impossible for the editor but it's better than create all the images for all the colors :)

Comment: The hex field needs a color picker on top, I just haven't had the time to do it yet.

Comment: I will put a link to a website with the list of the hex color on the field description. Should be fine for the moment :D I will use this module, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Bojan, i'm tring to get rid of "please wait" without using css(display:none) . I'm trying to use this function bartik_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 unset($form['product:commerce_price']['#ajax']['progress']['message']);
} but with no result. What's wrong with this?